# Stateful FeignClient (session between client and server)

Tags: spring-cloud, setcookie, jsessionid, stateful, spring-cloud-feign

I've been struggling with @FeignClient for Spring Cloud.
We have root "Gateway" WAR that calls "backend" services WARs where we cache user-role specific metadata (this data is supposed to be big enough to request it on every call and small enough to store it in RAM memory).

I need the client to be able to handle Set-Cookie and then put the JSESSIONID to the server side while client session is alive. So that I believe that I need to store all server's side sessionIds in some session-scoped bean for particular Gateway User. Like

```
"client1" => "8D06349922CD77D1CE68F78F4FAE04C5" 
"client2" => "another session id"
```

Having surfed the Internet I found solutions for ApacheHttpClient and for Spring RestTemplate. The only thing about Feign is that there's the ability to obtain @RequestHeader("Cookie") as an argument for remote function.

Well, I wrote some rude code that did the trick:

```
HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter = new HttpMessageConverter() {
            @Override
            public Object read(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
                HttpHeaders headers = inputMessage.getHeaders();
                logger.info("headers: {}", headers);
                List<String> setCookie = headers.get("Set-Cookie");
                logger.info("setCookie: {}", setCookie);
                if(setCookie != null){
                    String jsId = setCookie.get(0).split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
                    logger.info("jsId Object read: {}", jsId);
                    cookies.setSessionId("key", jsId);
                }
                return delegate.read(clazz,inputMessage);
            }
};
```

.....

```
RequestInterceptor jsessionFeignRequestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        String sessionId = cookies.getSessionId("key");
        logger.info("THE JSESSIONID: {}", sessionId);
        if(sessionId != null) {
            template.header("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);
        }
    }
};
```

....

```
 Feign.builder()
    .encoder(new SpringEncoder(new HttpMessageConverters(httpMessageConverter)))
    .requestInterceptor(jsessionFeignRequestInterceptor)
    .requestInterceptor(oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor)........
```

However it looks odd in my opinion.

Is there maybe some other "suitable option" to achieve similar functionality?

NOTE: we are using OAuth2 Spring Auth Server.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no option to achieve this out of the box.

Comment: Did you get any info on the 'right' way to achieve this ? I'm currently having the same question... Do you have some code to share ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar by using OkHttpClient with a custom Interceptor.

```java
Builder builder = Feign
    .builder()
    .client(new OkHttpClient(new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new SessionIdRequestInterceptor()).build()));
```

OkHttpClient also supports an Authenticator interface, but that is called only on 401 http status. Since my authentication server redirects to a login page with a 200 or 302, I had to make a custom validation of the authentication, hence the interceptor. Here's my implementation:

```java
class SessionIdRequestInterceptor implements okhttp3.Interceptor {

    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Request authenticatedRequest = authenticateRequest(chain.request());
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
        if (isAuthenticated(response)) {
            saveSessionId(response);
        } else if (jSessionId != null) {
            jSessionId = null;
            response.body().close();
            authenticatedRequest = authenticateRequest(authenticatedRequest);
            response = chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
        }
        if (!isAuthenticated(response)) {
            throw new PermissionDeniedException("Failed Authentication");
        }
        return response;
    }

    private void saveSessionId(okhttp3.Response response) {
        String setCookie = response.header("Set-Cookie");
        if (setCookie != null) {
            jSessionId = setCookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
        }
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated(okhttp3.Response response) {
        return !response.request().url().encodedPath().contains("/cas-server/login");
    }

    private okhttp3.Request authenticateRequest(okhttp3.Request request) {
        okhttp3.Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();
        if (jSessionId != null) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + jSessionId);
        } else {
            builder
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64
                    .getEncoder()
                    .encodeToString((configuration.getUser() + ":" + configuration.getClearPassword()).getBytes()));
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```